# SQLite SELECT default order with PRIMARY KEY ASC

Tags: sqlite, select

I've created a SQLite table using:

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (
  CN INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC,
  Name TEXT
);
```

If I do:

```
SELECT * FROM T1
```

Will I get the rows order by CN even without specifying a ORDER BY clause?
Is CN an alias to ROWID?

Comment: Rows in a relational table are **not** ordered. If you don't specify an `order by` the database is free to choose any order it likes. Any order you do see without having an `order by` is pure coincidence. So if you need to have a specific order, the only way to guarantee that is to use a proper `order by` clause.

Comment: And row_id is set based on the order the results are selected in. There's no secret row number attached to the data...

Comment: I understand, so I cannot avoid the ORDER BY. It's weird buy I get a penalty of about 10% of using ORDER BY even when the results are exact in the same order. I've suspected that the SELECT order was set by the PRIMARY KEY ASC. By the way, what's the difference between PRIMARY KEY ASC and PRIMARY KEY. Please, add an answer so I can select yours.

Comment: ASC is the default, so no difference. You shouldn't be getting penalised by order by CN by though. Unless it's some sqllite weirdness...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no such thing as a default order, if you need your results ordered add an explicit order by clause.

The dbms is simply optimised to look for the best way to quickly get the required data based on the query. In this case it's the primary key on CN, but that's only because your example is so simple. Never ever rely on the dbms choosing the order you want.

Answer (score 10):

The second question might be useful to others.

From the SQLite documentation:

*Except for WITHOUT ROWID tables, all rows within SQLite tables have a 64-bit signed integer key that uniquely identifies the row within its table. This integer is usually called the "rowid".

... if a rowid table has a primary key that consists of a single column and the declared type of that column is "INTEGER" in any mixture of upper and lower case, then the column becomes an alias for the rowid.*

This also holds for columns that are declared of type "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC", so in your table CN is an alias for "rowid"

Further information can be found here:
http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid