# SQlite primary key doesn't work as expeted

Tags: android, sqlite, primary-key

I have the following table:

```
    String sqlStatement = "CREATE TABLE " + CallsEntry.TABLE_NAME + "(";
    sqlStatement += CallsEntry.FIELD_CALL_ID + " INT PRIMARY KEY DESC,";
    sqlStatement += CallsEntry.FIELD_CALLER_PHONE + " TEXT,";
    sqlStatement += CallsEntry.FIELD_INSERTION_DATE_MILLIS + " INT); COMMIT;";

    db.execSQL(sqlStatement);
```

Please note that the primary key is descending.

Then I expect from my experience with SQL server that the following query will yield the records in an descending order:

```
SELECT * FROM tblCalls;
```

However, this is not the case. I'm getting the records in ascending order. I have to use this:

```
SELECT * FROM tblCalls ORDER BY CallId DESC;
```

Why is that? Can I do something differently and get the records in descending order?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21418425/sqlite-select-default-order-with-primary-key-asc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **no** such thing as default key order in `SQLite`.

Depends on [documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_select.html):

> If a SELECT statement that returns more than one row does not have an
>   ORDER BY clause, the order in which the rows are returned is
>   undefined. Or, if a SELECT statement does have an ORDER BY clause,
>   then the list of expressions attached to the ORDER BY determine the
>   order in which rows are returned to the user.

So default order is underfined without `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Does this produce the right order?

```
SELECT CallId FROM tblCalls
```