# SQLite order of the rows is juggled though primary key order is desc

Tags: sqlite, date, sql-order-by, primary-key

Have created a SQLite table as follows

```
CREATE TABLE HIST_DATA (DT INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DESC, DateOfEntry TEXT);
```

The primary key is UNIXEPOCH seconds. The insert query was

```
INSERT INTO HIST_DATA (DT, DateOfEntry) VALUES (strftime('%s', '2020-01-31', 'start of month'), '2020-01-31');
```

Fired the query

```
SELECT * FROM HIST_DATA;
```

The result is

```
DT          DateOfEntry
----------  -----------
1577836800  2020-01-31
1580515200  2020-02-28
1583020800  2020-03-31
1585699200  2020-04-30
1588291200  2020-05-31
1590969600  2020-06-30
1546300800  2019-01-31
1548979200  2019-02-28
1551398400  2019-03-31
1554076800  2019-04-30
1556668800  2019-05-31
```

Even after specifying DESC order on primary key why the table is not ordered in descending order of primary key? Can somebody guide me please?

---

Update:

I was looking to get the first row from the table without using `ORDER BY DT DESC` because I thought it will slow down the query and eventually the API which was simply a misconception. Can be achieved by simple `SELECT * FROM HIST_DATA ORDER BY DT DESC LIMIT 1;`.

Comment: Can you also include the actual query which generated the above result set?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM HIST_DATA ORDER BY DT DESC` would do what you want.

Comment: @GMB Displaying the table in desc order is fine but why the table is not in descending order is really bugging. My API design might fail if the table is not in descending order.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLite SELECT default order with PRIMARY KEY ASC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21418425/sqlite-select-default-order-with-primary-key-asc)

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS Tables are not ordered. Indexes can be ordered. Query result sets are (partially) ordered per an outermost order by.

Comment: @philipxy Apologies! Wasted half the day searching online. The question I've struggled a lot to find answer for was how to access first row which is easy for tables without a custom rowid or primary key i.e. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE rowid = 1`, but for tables with primary key we wouldn't really know the value of the rowid. So I was wondering is there a way to fetch the first row just like the above statement without using `ORDER BY DT DESC`. I found the simplest way is `SELECT * FROM HIST_DATA WHERE DT = (SELECT DT FROM HIST_DATA LIMIT 1);`

Comment: Rowid is the ordinal of a row as it is returned. The order of returned rows is any order that satisfies an outermost order by. Rownum is not determined for a row until all preceding rows have been returned; it isn't known in a WHERE; it is conceptually determined after SELECT. You don't seem to understand that tables have no order or how rownum is determined or used. PS Please clarify via edits, not comments. When you don't get what you expect, say what you expected & why--with justification by referencing authoritative documentation. So we can address misconceptions.

Comment: Also observed `SELECT * FROM HIST_DATA ORDER BY DT DESC LIMIT 1;` takes less time compared to `SELECT * FROM HIST_DATA WHERE DT = (SELECT DT FROM HIST_DATA LIMIT 1);`

Comment: "the simplest way is"--No. That just returns some row. LIMIT returns no particular row choice without ORDER BY. "Observed' does not tell you what the DBMS could also have done instead. "takes less time"--No. Again, you have fundamental misconceptions. PS Don't entertain personal theories. Believe what you can point to in authoritative documentation & what must logically follow from it. PS It's strange that you are still writing from misconceptions even after the comments & answers from other users here.

Comment: @philipxy I'm unable to get the technical jargon from documentation. That's why I've been relying on mere observations. Until you have clarified my doubts I had many misconceptions. That's why I've posted the question here. Thanks a lot again. Now I'll modify my API a little bit.

Comment: "Observation" is inadequate."Technical jargon" is words that are introduced & defined by definitions that you need to read. Read from the beginning. Follow a published academic/industrial textbook & official language/product documentation. (Not wiki articles or web posts.) Dozens are online free in pdf/html. Also basics are all SO faqs. (Although SO answers re basiscs are very often poor.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing DATA and INDEXES.

Your data enters your table following the time : The latest entered, the latest in the table. You might thus assume that its the logical order of your rows :: you would be wrong, because this ordering  is non-deterministic, meaning that if you don't specify an ORDER BY clause to your query, you might get resulting data in a random order.

Your query `SELECT * FROM HIST_DATA;` has kept the correct ordering (last-inserted), but consider this as LUCK only. Always beware that it might not always be the case if you dont specify an ORDER BY clause.

When you define a PRIMARY KEY DESC, it creates an index for which the greatest DT is the first in the index and the lowest DT is the last in the index. But that doesn't modify your data order at all. It just helps to `ORDER BY DT DESC` faster

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply @ThomasG and @GMB .I'm sorry I'm new to databases so my questions might look simple and stupid but what is the use of `PRIMARY KEY DESC`? One latest observation from my side is that `cursor.execute(SELECT DT FROM HIST_DATA).fetchone()` is returning 1590969600 which is correct. Can you kindly confirm `cursor.execute.fetchall()` or `cursor.execute.fetchone()` is not random?

Comment: As I said, the only use of DESC in your primary key, is to get the results faster when you do an `ORDER BY DT DESC`. and that is all. Regarding your cursor, in that state, it  will be random because there are no ORDER BY specified. Even you do it 1000 times and it always returns the the data correctly ordered, at one point, it will fail with the ordering. If you NEED the data ordered, you SHOULD specify an ORDER BY clause. And this is valid in all RDBMS, not only sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be assuming that the table has an inherent ordering, somehow based on the primary key, so that the following query would return rows in order:

```
SELECT * FROM HIST_DATA;
```

This is not the case. SQL tables represent unordered set of rows. There is no inherent ordering. The only way to get a sorted result is to add an `ORDER BY` clause to the query:

```
SELECT * FROM HIST_DATA ORDER BY DT DESC;
```

Without an `ORDER BY` clause, the ordering of the rows in the resultset is undefined. The database is free to order the rows as it likes, and the result may not necessarily be consistent over consequent executions of the same query.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply @ThomasG and @GMB .I'm sorry I'm new to databases so my questions might look simple and stupid but what is the use of `PRIMARY KEY DESC`? One latest observation from my side is that `cursor.execute(SELECT DT FROM HIST_DATA).fetchone()` is returning 1590969600 which is correct. Can you kindly confirm `cursor.execute.fetchall()` or `cursor.execute.fetchone()` is not random?

Comment: @saikrishna You cannot notify ThomasG via `@` on this post, they are neither the poster nor a commenter. See [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) to learn to use `@x` to notify one non-sole non-poster commenter `x` re a comment.